# a software program that allows me to draw on the screen while a video is playing and outputs a new video with the drawings on top of the old video?

Tags: video-editor, editing, software-recommendation, software, linux

As stated in the title, it is as simply as that. I need a piece of software that plays a video and then allows me to draw on top of the video and then the output will be a new video with the draws on top of the old video.

I have a linux mint operating system. I prefer free, of course. But is willing to pay.

Comment: You may want to look at collaboration software, rather than video editing software. I believe MS Teams and probably many other programs let you use a whiteboard or annotate a presentation. I think they may -- but I haven't confirmed -- let you share a video and use annotation tools. You might also want to check out Camtasia, although this would not be real-time annotation.

Comment: Zoom can do that as well and also support recording, but it's not really a video-editor